# Tiny spacecraft in orbit around light, boy in a mirror, and phone box made out of lego?

Tags: story-identification

This was a book written in 1987 +/- 3Y - aimed at kids.

It had a particular exchange on the radio when talking with aliens in a tiny spacecraft:

> Loost! Loost!
>
> Your name is Loost?
>
> Loost!
>
> Oh! They're saying they're lost!

It included:

- a yowie
- a boy in the mirror
- a phone box out of lego
- the family moved house
- a Dad that looked up things online (Compuserve?/Arpanet?)
- aliens in orbit around the light outside - see them in the telescope from the bathroom

My question is: **Can you remember the name of a book involving tiny spacecraft in orbit around light, boy in a mirror, and a phone box made out of lego?**

(A yowie is another word for bigfoot or yeti)

Comment: @Danny3414 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yowie

Comment: Did the boy travel from small planet to planet?

Comment: No - the Aliens came to visit outside.